# How do I make my XSLT show an element only when it is present?

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is part of my XML:

```
<ing>
    <amt>
        <qty>12</qty>
    </amt>
    <item>chicken thighs (boneless and skinned)</item>
</ing>
<ing>
    <amt>
        <qty>3</qty>
    </amt>
    <item>bay leaves</item>
</ing>
<ing>
    <amt>
        <qty>300</qty>
        <unit system="metric">gram(s)</unit>
    </amt>
    <item>oyster mushroom(s)</item>
    <prep>(torn into strips)</prep>
</ing>
```

Not every `<ing>` element has a `<prep>` element but I do not want the prep element line to be in the code if it is not in the XML.

Here is my current XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="recipeml/recipe/ingredients">
    <h2><xsl:text>Ingredients</xsl:text></h2> 
    <xsl:for-each select="ing">
        <li>
            <xsl:value-of select="item"/>
            <ul><xsl:value-of select="amt"/></ul>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="following-sibling::prep">
                    <ul><i><xsl:value-of select="prep"/></i></ul>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </li>
    </xsl:for-each> 
</xsl:template>
```

What I tried so far either gets me:

```
<li>oyster mushroom(s)
  <ul>
      300
      gram(s)
  </ul>
</li>
```

With no `<prep>` or every `<ing>` has one with many of them being empty (`<prep></prep>`)

Is there a way to make it show up only if there is a  element?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to make it show up only if there is a element?

Yes. Use template matching. Here, the `<xsl:template match="prep">` is only actually called when there is a `<prep>` element (i.e. when `select="prep"` selects anything).

```
<xsl:template match="ingredients">
    <h2><xsl:text>Ingredients</xsl:text></h2>
    <ul>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ing" />
    </ul>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ing">
    <li>
        <div class="item"><xsl:value-of select="item" /></div>
        <div class="amount"><xsl:value-of select="amt"/></div>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="prep" />
    </li>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="prep">
    <div class="preparation"><xsl:value-of select="." /></div>
</xsl:template>
```

I also corrected the HTML. Most of the elements you nested cannot legally be nested this way. It's much easier to work with CSS anyway, so I used `<div>` and CSS classes.

Answer (score 0):

you are already under the context of `ing` node in your for-each loop, change

```
<xsl:when test="following-sibling::prep">
```

to

```
<xsl:when test="prep">
```

to test for any child `prep` node